Is gnome-shell-extensions and gnome-shell-extensions-manager are same?
Is gnome-shell-extensions and gnome-shell-extensions-manager are same application? I have installed both and superficially both works the same.
Also when tried to uninstall "gnome-shell-extensions" using apt remove extensions its not removing the application at all. Although tried 2nd time and it says the directory does not exist.

You have a better chance of an answer if you add details. Like for example the version of Ubuntu being used? The exact commands used to install the apps? The exact command used to remove the app? https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

They are not the same. Compare the contents with dpkg -L gnome-shell-extensions and dpkg -L gnome-shell-extensions-manager. Also dpkg -l gnome-shell-extensions to see the installed ststus

No they are not the same, with shell extension manager you can also search for extensions., It is possible you added the extensions via AppCenter, and it is a snap software.Just go to the AppCenter search for extensions and remove. Next time please read what David DE suggested, actually all Help about the questions.
